# Where is JVM in Docker

Tags: java, docker, memory, jvm, docker-registry

Does Docker have its own JVM or Does it use Operating System JVM? I know Docker has a registry and it can take the java version and make it run the selected version but how if the JVM is outer the Container. How does it access (is it because same file system)

Comment: Docker itself does not use Java at all. Docker containers that need Java are almost always configured to use Java from the container image (that kind of isolation is sort of the point of containers).

Answer (score 4):

No, docker does not have it's own JVM. In fact, Docker and Java should be considered two entirely separate technologies. There's no requirement for a Docker container to have any java implementation installed.
Docker container images can include Java (and hence the JVM) in the same way they can include any other application inside the container. It would not be useful to attempt to use a JVM outside the container as this would create an external dependency that could not be guaranteed for every deployment of the container.